# Converting a string to a constraint "Term" in Solver Foundation

Tags: c#, linear-programming, ms-solver-foundation

I'm trying to use Solver Foundation to create an application which will be able to solve Linear Programming problems. Long story short I'm stuck when trying to convert a string expression to a Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Term.

What I want to do is add a string as a constraint to the Model, but first it has to be converted to a "Term".

```
SolverContext context = SolverContext.GetContext();
Model model = context.CreateModel();

Decision vz = new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "barrels_venezuela");
Decision sa = new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "barrels_saudiarabia");
Decision se = new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "barrels_saudiarabiad");
model.AddDecisions(vz,sa,se);

string theTerm = "(20 * sa) + (15 * vz) + (3 * se)";
Term T = (Term)theTerm;
model.AddConstraint("Name_of_constraint", T);
```

I tried casting (as above) but to no avail.

How can I go about to pass a string as an acceptable Term to the addConstraint Function?

Comment: What is `once` in the `Term T = (Term)once` line? Should it be `theTerm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is use the *full* names of the `Decision`:s rather than the names of the variables, and let the `AddConstraint(string, string)` overload do the parsing for you. Like this:

```
string theTerm = "(20 * barrels_saudiarabia) + 
                  (15 * barrels_venezuela) + (3 * barrels_saudiarabiad)";
model.AddConstraint("Name_of_constraint", theTerm);
```

For this to work, the expression string must of course comply with the rules of the [Optimization Modeling Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524507%28v=vs.93%29.aspx).

Comment: I understand, but I would like the user to specify the "Term", so it would typically come from a TextBox as a string..

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the question in the first place. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: You sir are a king.